# How to get rid of : Warning: Invalid value for prop `settaskstatus` on <span> tag

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created my own component , the following :

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

function StyledCheckbox(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    let iconClassName;
    if (!props.status) {
        iconClassName = classes.undoneIcon;
    } else if (props.status == 1) {
        iconClassName = classes.inProgressIcon;
    } else if (props.status == 2) {
        iconClassName = classes.checkedIcon;
    } else if (props.status == 3) {
        iconClassName = "taskStatusCheckboxCANCELED";
    }
    return (
        <Checkbox
            className={classes.root + " checklistTaskStyledCheckbox"}
            checkedIcon={<span className={clsx(classes.icon, iconClassName)} />}
            color="default"
            icon={<span className={iconClassName} />}
            {...props}
            onChange={() => {
                props.settaskstatus(props.message)
            }}
        />
    );
}
export default StyledCheckbox;
```

So as shown above i need to pass the function settaskstatus called in the onChange eventListener.
This used to be simple in react, here the previous shown component markup

```
                     <StyledCheckbox
                        status={this.state.status2}
                        message={this.props.message}
                        settaskstatus={this.setTaskStatus}
                     />
```

But now i'm getting this error

> backend.js:6 Warning: Invalid value for prop `settaskstatus` on 
>   tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number
>   value to keep it in the DOM. For details, see
>   www.fb.me/react-attribute-behavior
>       in span (created by ForwardRef(ButtonBase))
>       in ForwardRef(ButtonBase) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonBase)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be that you are passing { ...props } to `<Checkbox />` and `props` at that point includes `settaskstatus`, which is a custom attribute.

Try removing it and then passing the { ...rest } down.

https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Answer (score 1):

Try destructuring props into a `rest` object and `settaskstatus` like so:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

function StyledCheckbox(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    let iconClassName;
    if (!props.status) {
        iconClassName = classes.undoneIcon;
    } else if (props.status == 1) {
        iconClassName = classes.inProgressIcon;
    } else if (props.status == 2) {
        iconClassName = classes.checkedIcon;
    } else if (props.status == 3) {
        iconClassName = "taskStatusCheckboxCANCELED";
    }
    // See here:
    const {settaskstatus, ...rest} = props;
    // End see here :) 
    return (
        <Checkbox
            className={classes.root + " checklistTaskStyledCheckbox"}
            checkedIcon={<span className={clsx(classes.icon, iconClassName)} />}
            color="default"
            icon={<span className={iconClassName} />}
            {...rest}
            onChange={() => {
                settaskstatus(props.message)
            }}
        />
    );
}
export default StyledCheckbox;
```